# Markdown cells disappear when I double click

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I recently started using Jupyter notebooks, and sometimes when I double click on a cell the text will disappear.

Sometimes by double clicking the cell directly above I can get the cell to reappear, sometimes I cannot. I haven't been able to deduce the actual commands and what's going on. Does anyone know what I'm dealing with?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue! If I try to load a markdown cell or a cell with sympy code, the cells suddenly disappear and I have to switch the Jupiter lab notebook to "simple" (the left hand toggle) to see the cells again.... but then it happens all over and I have to switch it back! I have macOS Monterey

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).